# Sort child divs according to ids from an array giving error

Tags: jquery, sorting

I am trying to sort the child divs according to id values given in an array ,I dont know why its giving this error:

**Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .**

**throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );**

```
 var sortorder = item.data; 
 // where item.data is ["2896", "emptyone", "7787"]

          $("."+window.container).children("div").sort(function(a, b){

           return $.inArray(a.id, sortorder) > $.inArray(b.id, sortorder);
           }).appendTo("."+window.chosen_wardrobe);
```

*Where am I going wrong ?*

Comment: when i alert a.id or b.id...., it shows the ids of divs...so that is working fine

Comment: I think problem is with **$.inArray** .... is there any other alternative ?